# My BCH is marked 'unspendable' in my Blockchain Wallet

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash

My BCH is marked 'unspendable' in my blockchain wallet. I entered my public address instead of my private address by mistake when I exported the BCH from my paperwallet. Is that the problem and how do I correct this?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly! Just reset your wallet and then import your private key. It'll work like magic.